# How to scan a directory in php and print the name of all file names?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a directory which has mp3 files in it. Directory name is `outgoing_folder` and it has mp3 files in it.

*Here is the php code:*

```
$audio_mp3 = outgoing_folder;
scandir($audio_mp3);
print_r(scandir($audio_mp3));  // Added Line#A for debugging purpose
```

*Line#A prints the following:*

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => 36017P.mp3 [3] => 36031P.mp3 [4] => hello.mp3 )
```

The following **html/php** code output this `36017P.mp3`

`<td style="width:8%;text-align:center;"><?php echo $mp3_files[2];?></td>`

**Problem Statememnt:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the `php/html` code above so that it print the name of `all mp3 files`. At this moment, it is printing the name of only particular file.

Comment: What do you mean by "prints the name of all mp3 files" because your function is just doing that? Or maybe you're looking to print the file's full path instead?

Comment: No, this is printing `<?php echo $mp3_files[2];?>` only `36017P.mp3`. I am wondering what changes I should do in the php so that it print `36017P.mp3` `36031P.mp3` `hello.mp3`

Comment: You could try this

Wrap the html in a loop <?php
    foreach (array_diff(scandir($audio_mp3), array('..', '.')) as $file) : ?>
    <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;"><?php echo $file;?></td>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: @ElenaRoman why did you use curly braces at the last ?

Comment: my bad didn't notice :P. replace the curly braces with endforeach